# Yii2 Kartik FileInput widget force dimensions on image

Tags: php, file-io, widget, yii2, image-upload

I am using FileInput widget for yii2 by Kartik.

```
// your fileinput widget for single file upload
echo $form->field($model, 'image')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
'options'=>['accept'=>'image/*'],
'pluginOptions'=>['allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg','gif','png']
]);
```

The above checks that the image is of type jpg,gif or png. I want to check if the file is of a specified dimensions and also probably file size if that is possible.

Has anyone used Kartik FileInput widget and enforced dimensions for an image?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do enforce image sizes with the kartik widget, but you can use the built-in [image validator in Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-imagevalidator.html). Using that you can specify maximum and minimum dimension for your images.